# win10 tensorflow gpu dont work:Device mapping: no known devices

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I had install:
1. **cuda_8.0.61_win10.exe**
2. unzip **cudnn-8.0-windows10-x64-v6.0.zip** and copy **.dll、.h、.lib** in `bin 、 include、 lib` to the path `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\`
3.add `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\bin` to the %PATH%

but is did`t work when run

`Device mapping: no known devices.
Device mapping: no known devices.
add_yx: (Add): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
_retval_add_yx_0_0: (_Retval): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
b: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
a: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0`

my evn: **win10、gtx970、TensorFlow 1.2**
I had try to reinstall the driver of gtx970, but it still does`t work
pls help!

`C:\Users\Wilker>nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Mon_Jan__9_17:32:33_CST_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.60`

`C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\extras\demo_suite>deviceQuery.exe
  deviceQuery.exe Starting...
   CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)
  Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)
  Device 0: "GeForce GTX 970"
    CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          8.0 / 8.0
    CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    5.2
    Total amount of global memory:                 4096 MBytes (4294967296 bytes)
    (13) Multiprocessors, (128) CUDA Cores/MP:     1664 CUDA Cores
    GPU Max Clock rate:                            1266 MHz (1.27 GHz)
    Memory Clock rate:                             3505 Mhz
    Memory Bus Width:                              256-bit
    L2 Cache Size:                                 1835008 bytes
    Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(65536), 2D=(65536, 65536), 3D=(4096, 4096, 4096)
    Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(16384), 2048 layers
    Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(16384, 16384), 2048 layers
    Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
    Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
    Total number of registers available per block: 65536
    Warp size:                                     32
    Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  2048
    Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
    Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)
    Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (2147483647, 65535, 65535)
    Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
    Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
    Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 2 copy engine(s)
    Run time limit on kernels:                     Yes
    Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
    Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
    Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
    Device has ECC support:                        Disabled
    CUDA Device Driver Mode (TCC or WDDM):         WDDM (Windows Display Driver Model)
    Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
    Device PCI Domain ID / Bus ID / location ID:   0 / 1 / 0
    Compute Mode:
       < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >
  deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 8.0, CUDA Runtime Version = 8.0, NumDevs = 1, Device0 = GeForce GTX 970
  Result = PASS`

Comment: Can you run `nvcc -V` in a command prompt and share the output? Also run `CUDA Samples\v8.0\bin\win64\Release\deviceQuery.exe` and check the output (more information can be found [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/#verify-installation)). Note that in order to use `tensorflow` you also need to install [NVIDIA cuDNN](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn). Also make sure that your graphics card is the active device (can be seen in the NVIDIA control center usually). Maybe your computer runs with the Intel on-board graphics at the moment.